# Multiple EditText by clicking: how to make the keyboard stay?

Tags: android-edittext, keyboard, listener

**My layout**

In my layout, there are multiple `EditText`s, when I click on the one of `EditText`s, the keyboard pop up, that is ok.

**Problem**

Then, I click on another `EditText`, I would like the keyboard stays, rather than disappear and appear again.

Comment: Ideally, that should not happen. If still, that is an issue, you can try with android:imeOptions with your EditText.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example